# TypeError: clicking() takes exactly 0 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, screen, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to create a simple clicker style game. But lately I've been having some issues. In a previous question of mine I  asked how can I solve a `screen = getscreen()` error. That question was answered but the same day I got a new error.

When I try to click the button I get this traceback error:

```
TypeError: clicking() takes exactly 0 arguments (2 given) at <unknown>`.
```

It links back to the definition of `clicking()`.

Part of code in which `clicking()` is defined:

```
def clicking():
  if distance( button.pos() ) < 2:
    BUTTON_CLICKS = BUTTON_CLICKS + 1
```

The whole code:

```
import time
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
image_BUTTON = "Button.png"
image_BUTTON_CLICKS = "Button_clicks.png"
image_UPGRADEBG = "UPGRADEBG.png"

button = turtle.Turtle()
BUTTON_CLICKS = 0
BUTTON_CLICKS1 = turtle.Turtle()
BUTTON_CLICKS2 = turtle.Turtle()
upgrade = turtle.Turtle()
upgrade1 = turtle.Turtle()
upgrade2 = turtle.Turtle()
upgrade3 = turtle.Turtle()
upgrade4 = turtle.Turtle()
upgrade5 = turtle.Turtle()

screen.addshape(image_BUTTON)
button.penup()
button.speed(0)
button.left(90)
button.shape(image_BUTTON)
button.goto(0, 0)

BUTTON_CLICKS1.speed(0)
BUTTON_CLICKS1.penup()
BUTTON_CLICKS1.hideturtle()
BUTTON_CLICKS1.goto(-65, 170)
BUTTON_CLICKS1.write("Button   clicks: %d" % BUTTON_CLICKS, font=("Bebas", 14, "bold"))

upgrade.speed(0)
upgrade.penup()
upgrade.hideturtle()
upgrade.goto(110, -190)
upgrade.write("Upgrades", font=("Bebas", 13, "bold"))

def clicking():
  if distance( button.pos() ) < 2:
    BUTTON_CLICKS = BUTTON_CLICKS + 1

screen = turtle.getscreen()
screen.onclick( clicking )
```

**Note:** I'm creating this game in `trinket.io`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` accepts a function as an argument and calls it using two other arguments, the coordinates of the point clicked.

**[From the documentation:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.onclick)**

> `turtle.onclick(fun, btn=1, add=None)¶`
>
> Parameters: 
>       *fun – a function with two arguments which will be called with the coordinates of the clicked point on the canvas*

(emphasis mine)

As a result, when you supply a function (`clicking()`) which *doesn't take any arguments*, a `TypeError` is going to get raised because `onclick` will call it with two arguments.

Add two arguments to your function to remove the `TypeError`, what you do with these, is up to you to decide.

```
def clicking(x, y):
  if distance( button.pos() ) < 2:
    BUTTON_CLICKS = BUTTON_CLICKS + 1
```

Comment: Hah, I don't get that error anymore. But I get a `NameError: name 'distance' is not defined on line 41`. (Sorry for being so dumb) I'm clearly missing something?

Comment: You haven't defined `distance`, why have added it there?

Comment: I'm learning through an internet course. I didn't see a definition in the example there. So I thought I didn't need one. How do I define it?

Comment: Well, it's a function (because it is called) you need to define a new function with `def distance(button_position): # added logic` that implements something. I don't know what that something is, the internet course **should** provide it.

Comment: It doesn't. And it's kind of abandoned so I won't get a response for sure. Can you help me a bit on this one? How do I make the button click. I'm so lost.

Comment: The comments here don't really allow such explanation. A working example can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893236/python-3-0-using-turtle-onclick) or an interactive guide like [this](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/thinkcspy/PythonTurtle/OurFirstTurtleProgram.html) one. Seriously though, google these things and try them out in the interpreter; `turtle` is a pretty popular library so resources are plentyfull. :-)

Comment: Thanks for you help, Jim. I'll try to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.onclick) (emphasis mine):

> `turtle.onclick(fun, btn=1, add=None)`
>
> Parameters:
>
> `fun` – a function
>   **with two arguments which will be called with the coordinates of the
>   clicked point on the canvas**
>
> `num` – number of the mouse-button, defaults
>   to 1 (left mouse button)
>
> `add` – True or False – if True, a new binding
>   will be added, otherwise it will replace a former binding Bind fun to
>   mouse-click events on this turtle.

Your function takes 0 arguments, and docs specifies that it should accept exactly two arguments.

Change your function signature to:

```
def clicking(x, y):
    pass  # your code goes here
```