# Binding an event when a shape is clicked in 'turtle'

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I generate random figures on the screen. I want the screen to clear when I click on any circle shape. How to bind an event when a circle is clicked? I tried `onclick()` with `clearscreen()`, but it doens't work.
My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random
import turtle
class Figure:
    def __init__(self):
        __colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'orange']
        __figures = ['square', 'circle', 'triangle']
        self.__x = random.randint(-330, 330)
        self.__y = random.randint(-230, 230)
        self.__color = random.choice(__colors)
        self.t = turtle.Turtle()
        self.t.hideturtle()
        self.t.fillcolor(self.__color)
        self.t.up()
        self.t.setpos(self.__x, self.__y)
        self.t.down()
        __choose = random.choice(__figures)
        if __choose == 'square':
            self.square()
        elif __choose == 'circle':
            self.circle()
        else:
            self.triangle()


    def square(self):
        self.t.begin_fill()
        for i in range(4):
            self.t.fd(50)
            self.t.left(90)
        self.t.end_fill()


    def circle(self):
        self.t.begin_fill()
        self.t.circle(50)
        self.t.end_fill()
        self.t.onclick(self.delete_figures)
        
    def triangle(self):
        self.t.begin_fill()
        self.t.fd(50)
        self.t.lt(120)
        self.t.fd(50)
        self.t.lt(120)
        self.t.fd(50)
        self.t.end_fill()

    def delete_figures(self, x ,y):
        turtle.clearscreen()



turtle.tracer(1, 0)

for i in range(10):
    Figure()


turtle.mainloop()
```

I want the screen to clear when I click on any circle shape. How to bind an event when a circle is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclick` doesn't register a click listener on drawings the turtle has made, only on the turtle itself. But these turtles are hidden and only a few pixels large even if visible, so there's nothing to click.

There are two main options:

1. Keep the turtle drawing the same and add a screen click listener. In the click handler, loop over all of your circles and determine if the x/y position of the click occurred within the radius of any circle. Here's an example:

   ```py
   import random
   import turtle


   class Figure:
       def __init__(self):
           __colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'orange']
           __figures = ['square', 'circle', 'triangle']
           self.__x = random.randint(-330, 330)
           self.__y = random.randint(-230, 230)
           self.__color = random.choice(__colors)
           self.t = turtle.Turtle()
           self.t.hideturtle()
           self.t.fillcolor(self.__color)
           self.t.up()
           self.t.setpos(self.__x, self.__y)
           self.t.down()
           self.shape = random.choice(__figures)

           if self.shape == 'square':
               self.square()
           elif self.shape == 'circle':
               self.circle()
           else:
               self.triangle()

       def square(self):
           self.t.begin_fill()

           for i in range(4):
               self.t.fd(50)
               self.t.left(90)

           self.t.end_fill()

       def circle(self):
           self.t.begin_fill()
           self.t.circle(50)
           self.t.end_fill()
           self.t.right(90)
           self.t.forward(-50)

       def triangle(self):
           self.t.begin_fill()
           self.t.fd(50)
           self.t.lt(120)
           self.t.fd(50)
           self.t.lt(120)
           self.t.fd(50)
           self.t.end_fill()

       def is_touching(self, x, y):
           return self.shape == 'circle' and self.t.distance(x, y) < 50


   turtle.tracer(1, 0)
   figures = []

   for i in range(10):
       figures.append(Figure())

   def test_circle_click(x, y):
       for f in figures:
           if f.is_touching(x, y):
               turtle.clearscreen()

   turtle.onscreenclick(test_circle_click)
   turtle.mainloop()
   ```
2. Instead of drawing circles, use `turtle.shape("circle")` and `turtle.color()` to make the turtle look like a circle. Don't hide the turtle to allow it to be clickable using your current handler. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676484/6243352) (and [an answer in this thread from the author of that other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77922487/6243352)).

Answer (score 2):

Building on @ggorlen's second option (+1), here's an example implementation of such.  One difference is that although squares still do nothing when clicked, triangles will remove themselves (only) and circles will remove everything:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint, choice

class Figure:
    COLORS = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'orange']
    FIGURES = ['square', 'circle', 'triangle']

    def __init__(self):
        x = randint(-330, 330)
        y = randint(-230, 230)
        color = choice(self.COLORS)

        self.turtle = Turtle()
        self.turtle.hideturtle()
        self.turtle.fillcolor(color)
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.setpos(x, y)

        figure = choice(self.FIGURES)
        self.turtle.shape(figure)
        self.turtle.shapesize(3)

        if figure == 'circle':
            self.turtle.onclick(self.delete_figures)
        elif figure == 'triangle':
            self.turtle.onclick(self.delete_figure)

        self.turtle.showturtle()

    def delete_figure(self, x, y):
        self.turtle.hideturtle()

    def delete_figures(self, x, y):
        self.turtle.screen.clear()


screen = Screen()

for _ in range(10):
    Figure()

screen.mainloop()
```