# Get 2 positions from onclick() of Python Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm makin Tic Tac Toe game and I have already search for how to get 2 positions with onclick() of Python Turtle. The thing I got is just on this link :
[Python 3.0 using turtle.onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893236/python-3-0-using-turtle-onclick).
I want to get 2 positions but I have a problem with "turtle.mainloop()" 
My Solution is:

```
def getPosX(x_X, y_X):

    print("(", x_X, ",", y_X,")")

def getPosO(x_O, y_O):

    print("(", x_O, ",", y_O,")"

def choiceX():

      Xplay = turtle.getscreen()

      Xplay.onclick(getPosX)

      turtle.mainloop()

      return Xplay


def choiceO():

      Oplay = turtle.getscreen()

      Oplay.onclick(getPosO)

      turtle.mainloop()

      return Oplay
```

What I got just like it just takes the postion of Xplay.onclick().

And I also try to delete the " turtle.mainloop()" of each def to use the for loop in another def:

```
   def play():
       for i in range(3):
            choiceX()
            choiceO()
       return i
```

and it doesn't work.
I think I need the better measure 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want your turtle clicks to alternate between X and O, that is between `getPosX()` and `getPosO()`.  I believe this rearrangement of your code should do what you want:

```
import turtle

def getPosX(x, y):

    print("X: (", x, ",", y, ")")

    choiceO()

def getPosO(x, y):

    print("O: (", x, ",", y, ")")

    choiceX()

def choiceX():

    screen.onclick(getPosX)

def choiceO():

    screen.onclick(getPosO)

screen = turtle.Screen()

choiceX()  # X goes first

turtle.mainloop()
```

Clicking around the screen, I get:

```
> python3 test.py
X: ( -206.0 , 178.0 )
O: ( 224.0 , 31.0 )
X: ( -14.0 , -122.0 )
O: ( -41.0 , 159.0 )
X: ( 146.0 , 196.0 )
O: ( 105.0 , -70.0 )
X: ( -100.0 , -114.0 )
O: ( -179.0 , 184.0 )
X: ( 23.0 , 137.0 )
```

When I see more than one `mainloop()` call (or any `mainloop()` call not at the top level nor the last thing in the program) it usually indicates a misunderstanding of what `mainloop()` does.

You set up your event handlers to do what you want and then turn complete control over to `mainloop()` for the remainder of the program.  It will arrange for your event handers to be called when the events of interest occur.