# How to make text into a button in python turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to make the word "CAT" into a button, so when it's clicked it says "CAT". Also, the button I want should be in the position that the word is right now when it's not a button. Any help provided is needed. Thank you

I have already tried the tkinter module, but the problem with that is it opens a separate window with the button. What I want is a button on the main screen.

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()

# this assures that the size of the screen will always be 400x400 ...
screen.setup(800,800)
turtle.ht()
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto (50, 200)
turtle.color("black")
turtle.write("CAT", move=False, align="center", font=("Times New Roman", 120, "bold"))
screen.bgpic("background.gif")
turtle.st()
turtle.forward(145)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(10)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(110)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(287)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(110)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(287)
turtle.ht()
```

I expect the output to be a huge button (in black) at the top of the screen saying "CAT". When that button is pressed, I want it to say "CAT" out loud. Right now there is just text at the top saying "CAT". I want to replace that text with a button saying the same thing. If I use on screen click I want the click to be in specific coordinates. How would I do that. 
Thank You!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.0 using turtle.onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893236/python-3-0-using-turtle-onclick)

Comment: so how can I make the text a button??

Comment: can't you draw rectangle which can look like button and put text on it. Using `onscreenclick` you can check if mouse clicked in rectangle.

Comment: I made the rectangle. How could I check if mouse clicked in the rectangle?

Comment: you can use `onscreenclick(function_name)` to run `function_name(x,y)` when you click mouse button. It gets position `(x,y)` of this click and you can check - ie. `if 0 < x < 100 and 0 < y < 100:`

Comment: I edited the question to the new code with the rectangle. I don't want to change the background or anything else. All I want is when the user clicks inside the rectangle, it says "CAT" out loud.

Answer (score 1):

You could use turtle do draw rectangle which could look like button. And you can use `onscreenclick(check_button)` to run function `check_button` when you click screen. If you clicked in rectangle then it could run function which does something.

```
import turtle

def show_cat():
    turtle.ht()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto (15, 220)
    turtle.color("black")
    turtle.write("CAT", move=False, align="center", font=("Times New Roman", 120, "bold"))

def check_button(x, y):
    if -300 < x < 300 and 200 < y < 400:
        show_cat()

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(800,800)

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-300, 200)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.fillcolor('red')
turtle.fd(600)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.fd(300)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.fd(600)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.fd(300)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.onscreenclick(check_button)

turtle.mainloop()
```

Or you can use `tk.Button` with `canvas.master` as its parent, and put it on canvas using `create_window(x, y, window=widget)`

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk

def show_cat():
    turtle.ht()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto (15, 220)
    turtle.color("black")
    turtle.write("CAT", move=False, align="center", font=("Times New Roman", 120, "bold"))

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(800,800)

canvas = screen.getcanvas()

button = tk.Button(canvas.master, text="Click Me", command=show_cat)
canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=button)

#canvas.create_rectangle((100, 100, 700, 300))

turtle.mainloop()
```

The same way you can put other tkinter's widgets on canvas

**EDIT:** example with more widgets

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk

def show_cat():
    label = tk.Label(canvas.master, text="Cat", font=("Times New Roman", 120, "bold"))
    canvas.create_window(0, -300, window=label)

    canvas.create_text(0, 300, text="HELLO", fill="red", font=("Times New Roman", 120, "bold"))

#-------------------------------------------

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(800,800)

canvas = screen.getcanvas()

button = tk.Button(canvas.master, text="Click Me", command=show_cat)
canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=button)

turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

We could take advantage of the object-oriented nature of turtle to define our own reusable button class for generating multiple buttons:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class Button(Turtle):
    FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_TYPE = 'Arial', 18, 'normal'

    HORIZONTAL_PAD, VERTICAL_PAD = 1.05, 1.15

    def __init__(self, text, position, command=None):
        super().__init__(visible=False)
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.penup()

        self.text = text
        self.position = position
        self.command = command

        self.width, self.height = self.drawButton()

    def drawButton(self):
        x, y = self.position
        self.setposition(x, y - self.FONT_SIZE/2)
        button_font = (self.FONT_NAME, self.FONT_SIZE, self.FONT_TYPE)
        self.write(self.text, align='center', move=True, font=button_font)

        width = 2 * (self.xcor() - x) * self.HORIZONTAL_PAD
        height = self.FONT_SIZE * self.VERTICAL_PAD

        self.setposition(x - width/2, y - height/2)
        self.pendown()

        for _ in range(2):
            self.forward(width)
            self.left(90)
            self.forward(height)
            self.left(90)

        self.penup()

        return width, height

    def clickButton(self, x, y):
        c_x, c_y = self.position
        half_w, half_h = self.width/2, self.height/2

        if c_x - half_w < x < c_x + half_w and c_y - half_h < y < c_y + half_h:
            (self.command)(x, y)

screen = Screen()

cyan = Button("Cyan Background", (100, 100), lambda x, y: screen.bgcolor('cyan'))

screen.onclick(cyan.clickButton, add=True)

yellow = Button("Yellow Background", (-100, -100), lambda x, y: screen.bgcolor('yellow'))

screen.onclick(yellow.clickButton, add=True)

screen.mainloop()
```

Embellish as you see fit.