# How to make multiple buttons in python's turtle module without hardcore

Tags: python, system, turtle-graphics, python-3.7

I want to make a turtle python 'app' with buttons. I know how to make a button, but i want to make 1+ buttons there and WITHOUT ANY big HARDCORE, please.

I saw instructions on YouTube and read comments, a man asked such question, and the YTBer answered 'yes. you'll need some hardcore' something like that. I don't want a hardcore.

...you are right it doesn't work when using 2 buttons, I realized that after making the video but luckily I have found a solution for that....... so the reason it doesn't work is because two buttons requires the turtle.onscreenclick method to listen for two object's methods and it cant do that for some reason so we could just hardcode it in the class by the following way:

```py
import turtle
import time

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("Green")
wn.setup(700, 700)
wn.tracer(0)

class Button(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self,s, text, x, y, w, h, c, i, p, a=None, b2=None):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.msg = text
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.pens...
```

I tried to exec() the cdlane's code, but I got

```py
I got a


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 60, in <module>
    ''')
  File "<string>", line 51, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 10, in __init__
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 3816, in __init__
    visible=visible)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 2557, in __init__
    self._update()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 2646, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

Used the exec('') command

Comment: See this [recent answer about creating a turtle button class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56961963/5771269).  It does work with 2 or more buttons by using the `add` parameter to `onscreenclick()`

Comment: I tried to exec() the code but I got an error above.

Comment: I just copied the code and pasted it into a file and it runs fine under Python3.  Why are you using `exec('')` to run it?

Comment: it is very unusual to use `exec()` - can't you run `python script.py` or `import script` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`turtle` is built on top of `tkinter` and `tkinter.Canvas` so you can use `tkinter.Button` and other widgets and add to canvas.

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk

def test1():
    print("clicked World")

def test2():
    print("clicked World")

canvas = turtle.getcanvas()
parent = canvas.master

button1 = tk.Button(parent, text='Hello', command=test1)
id1 = canvas.create_window((0,0), window=button1)

button2 = tk.Button(parent, text='World', command=test2)
id2 = canvas.create_window((100,0), window=button2)

turtle.done()
```

`Button` needs parent - here can be only `canvas.master`. If you forgot parent then it will create tkinter's window and you will see two windows.

`command=` expect function's name without `()` and parameters. It runs this function when you click button.

`Button` has other options like `background`, `font`, etc.

`create_window` is used to add any tkinter's widget. First parameter is its position on canvas. It has other options.

`crete_window` gives ID which you can use to remove widget `canvas.delete(ID)` or move it `canvas.move(ID, offset_x, offset_y)`

---

Tkinter: [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm), [Button](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm), [more widgets](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm#class-reference)

---

**EDIT:** it creates 10 buttons and every button use `lambda` to assign function with parameters. Every button changes text on `Label`

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk

def test(value):
    print("clicked", value)
    label['text'] = str(value)

canvas = turtle.getcanvas()
parent = canvas.master

label = tk.Label(parent, text="???")
canvas.create_window((0, -30), window=label)

for x in range(10):
    text = 'Button {}'.format(x)
    button = tk.Button(parent, text=text, command=(lambda val=x:test(val)))
    canvas.create_window((0, x*30), window=button)

turtle.done()
```

Comment: But how to delete the buttons then?

Comment: you can use `ID` returned by  `create_window()`. In first code it will be `canvas.delete(id1)` . In second example when it create Buttons in loop you would have to keep IDs on list. You can also first add button to canvas and later assign function to button and add this ID as argument `button['command'] = lambda val=x, id_=ID: test(val, id_))` so you can use this ID inside function `test()`

Comment: you can also use `canvas.delete("all")` to remove all widgets from canvas. It removes all widgets create with `create_window()` (not only Buttons) but also objects create with `create_line()`, `create_image()`, `create_oval()`, `create_polygon()`, ect. More `create_XXX` on page [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)

Comment: and how to add picts to them?

Comment: you have it in links to Button and Canvas in my answer. To add image to Button  - [Button( image=... )](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm), to canvas - [canvas.create_image( (x,y), image=...)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method). In both situations it has to be [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm). Because `tkinter` can work only with GIF images (currently maybe it can works with PNG too) so you may need `PIL.ImageTk` to load JPG or PNG but you have it in link for PhotoImage.

Comment: and read `Note` in PhotoImage about problem with garbage-collector which removes images from memory so tkitner doesn't shows images.

Comment: like Button(image=PhotoImage('wat.gif'))?

Comment: did you check my links to Button and PhotoImage ? Did you try to use it before you ask ?

Comment: example in link shows that `PhotoImage` uses `file=` and this is important. There can be also problem w garbage-collector if you don't assign `PhotoImage` to global variable - so use `img = PhotoImage(file="wat.gif')` and then use `Button(root, image=img)`