# How do I define a starting position and end position and then tell turtle to connect them

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I wanna click once to set the origin of the line then move the mouse and click the second time to draw the line from the previously set origin to the current location of the mouse pointer

I tried setpos(x,y) and then goto(x,y) but that didnt work
Can you help me

```
import turtle
beni=turtle.Screen()
beni.setup(900,700)
t=turtle.Turtle()



def freehandmode(x, y):
    t.ondrag(None)
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.ondrag(freehandmode)

t.ondrag(freehandmode)


def linemode(x, y):
    t.setposition(x,y)
    t.goto(x, y)


turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: It will help if you share your code and elaborate what exactly didn't work.

Comment: just added the code for you to see

Comment: Hello, Benedict. Please post also the output when you try to run this code. Also describe what you're expecting to happen and how precisely that is not happening. Voting to leave the question open, pending Benedict's output.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems. First, you need to keep the current state: whether you're currently drawing a line. Second, as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15893236/770830), you need to call `onclick` on the `Screen` object, or `turtle.onscreenclick`. With these two fixes the program will look like:

```
import turtle
beni = turtle.Screen()
beni.setup(900,700)

class Drawer:
    def __init__(self):
       self.drawing = False

    def click(self, x, y):
        if self.drawing:
            turtle.down()
            turtle.goto(x, y)
            self.drawing = False
        else:
            turtle.up()
            turtle.goto(x, y)
            self.drawing = True

d = Drawer()
beni.onclick(d.click)

turtle.up()
turtle.mainloop()
```